# appropriate method to read ungridded lat / long csv as raster in python?

Tags: python, geospatial, raster, spatial, rasterio

I have a csv file or data.frame of un-gridded latitude/longitude coordinates which I would like to coerce to a raster object in python (e.g. ideally using `rasterio`).

While GDAL's 'xyz' driver only accepts gridded coordinates in a text file, spatial packages in R are happy to do this coercion from a data frame to a raster object in one line, like this:

```r
df <- readr::read_csv("https://minio.carlboettiger.info/shared-data/gbif.csv")
r <- terra::rast(df, crs="epsg:4326")
terra::plot(r)
```

[image: r plot of raster]

I'd love to find the analogously concise command in python (preferably in `rasterio`) but haven't been able to figure this out.  I realize I can get a spatial *vector* object of points as simple features, e.g. using geopandas, but that's not what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below was provided by `scottyhq` on the [Pangeo discourse](https://discourse.pangeo.io/t/generate-a-raster-from-non-gridded-lat-longs-in-rasterio-python/3245/2)

I really like this approach, as it is a bit more explicit about the resolution and [grid interpolation](https://gdal.org/tutorials/gdal_grid_tut.html#gdal-grid-tut)

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from geocube.rasterize import rasterize_points_griddata # Different choices here

# Ordinary Dataframe
df = gpd.pd.read_csv('https://minio.carlboettiger.info/shared-data/gbif.csv')

# GeoDataFrame
gf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, 
                      geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude), 
                      crs=4326)

# Rasterize Points to Gridded Xarray Dataset
geo_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=gf,
    measurements=['n'],
    resolution=0.25, # degrees
    rasterize_function=rasterize_points_griddata,
)

geo_grid.n.plot(cmap='gray_r');
```